# Final аргумент

Tags: java

Добрый день. Читаю про final и наткнулся на такой пример :

```
public class Application {
int g (final int i){
    return i + 1;
}
void f (final int i) {
    i++ ;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application a = new Application();
    System.out.println(a.g(6));
}
```

}

Скажите, почему в методе g() значение переменной i увеличилось ? Ведь эта локальная переменная и она объявлена как final, а значит не может быть переопределена ? В учебнике "ThinkingInJava" написано, что мы можем только читать финальную переменную. Но тут мы ее не читаем, мы пытаемся поменять ее значения и это отлично получилось, но я не понял, как все таки final работает ? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: может я туплю, но разве возвращать новое значение не одно и тоже, что и изменить переменную ? i было равно 6 , после выполнения метода g() переменная i  стала равна 7 ?

Comment: >может я туплю

совершенно верно, причем жестоко. Возвращая i + 1, вы не меняете саму i. Грубо говоря, вы создаете новую переменную, присваиваете ей значение (именно значение, а не адрес) переменной i, прибавляете единицу и возвращаете уже эту новую переменную. С i вы ничего не делаете, а только читаете значение, хранящееся в ней.

Answer (score 3):

Элементарно же. Вы не изменяете переменную **i**, а возвращаете новое значение, равное **i + 1**. И еще, у вас очевидно опечатка - метод **f()** вряд ли может иметь возвращаемый тип v**oid**, если возвращает **i + 1**

Comment: действительно ошибся. исправил.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вам стоит обратить внимание на эту статью : [Передача по ссылке и по значению в Java](http://www.isramir.com/content/view/3290/196/)

т.к. вы передаёте примитивное значение, оно меняется внутри функции и возвращает результат. Модификатор **final** в вашем случае значит что ее нельзя перезаписать. Вы её и не перезаписываете(компилятор бы не дал вам скомпилировать такой код)

Вглядитесь в код и вы поймёте что возвращаете не **i** а новое сформированное число. Число **i** остаётся прежним.

Comment: спасибо. но все равно. ведь метод g() не должен был изменить i ?

Comment: @Drylozav обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

final в этом контексте - это аналог const в С++. Тоесть вы указываете компилятору и пользователю этого метода, что метод не изменяет переданного ей значения. Но если вы случайно по ошибке попытаетесь изменить его, то компилятор вернет ошибку, тоесть вы еще и себя страхуете от случайного изменения этой переменной.

```
return i + 1; // Значит, что вы возвращаете новую переменную без имени, а не изменяете i, эта запись аналогична tmp = i + l; return tmp;
return i++; // Не допустимо, так как инкремент изменяет значение i, тоесть i++ аналогично ( с некоторой оговоркой, которую здесь не описываю ) i = i + 1
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Я отловился, программируя на андроиде, с этим final.
Чтобы его можно было использовать в перегруженной функции onDone, среда программирования предложила мне указать final для переменной locale.
Так вот, при повторном вызове статической функции run, передавая туда параметр locale уже какой-нибудь другой в метод onDone попадало старое значение.

Чтобы такого не было, добавил static mLocale в этом классе и пересохраняю этот входящий параметр. Вот так работает как положено:

public class Class {

```
private static TextToSpeech tts;
private static Context mContext;
private static String mText;
private static Locale mLocale;

public static void run(Context context, String text, Locale locale) {
    mContext = context;
    mLocale = locale;
    mText = text;
    if(tts == null)
    tts = new TextToSpeech(mContext, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                        tts.setLanguage(mLocale);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}